# Javascript: Stop/Skip function from executing if condition is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a `tweet();` function in a cronjob that executes every hour, and in one of my files used to get data for that function I have an if else statement. What I want to do is; if the statement is true, I want the `tweet()` function not to execute at that time, and since this is an hourly cronjob it should just skip execution for that hour but the app should still be running, it shouldn't stop or crash or anything. How would I do this?

**index.js (Where the tweet/cron is executed)**

```
// MODULES
const rwClient = require("./TwitterClient.js");
const cronjob = require("cron").CronJob;
const priceModule = require("./price");
const nameModule = require("./name");
const dateModule = require("./date");
const stockModule = require("./stock");
const numShares = require("./numShares.js");

(async () => {

    // Async function that creates the Tweet
    const tweet = async () => {
        try {
            await rwClient.v2.tweet(
                //
                "New insider trade! (form 4 filed)" + '\n' + '\n' +
                await nameModule() + " bought " + await numShares() + " shares at " + "$" + await priceModule() + '\n' + '\n' +
        
                "Total Amount Purchased: " + "$" + await numShares() * await priceModule() + '\n' +
                "Stock: " +  await stockModule() + '\n' +
                "Date: " + await dateModule() + '\n'
            );

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    // CronJob, starts from 10 am to 8pm EST
    const job = new cronjob("0 14-23 * * *", () => {
        tweet();
        console.log("Tweet executed");
    });

    job.start();
  
})();
```

**price.js, file with the if statement**

```
// MODULES
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

// Url where we get and scrape the data from
const url = "https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/dateRange=30d&category=custom&forms=4";

let browser;
module.exports = () => (async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    //Set User Agent
    const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
    await page.setUserAgent(ua);

    //Go to page from URL and reload
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", timeout: 0});
    await page.reload({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

    //Get success response and check if url ends with .xml
    const responseP = page.waitForResponse(res =>
      res.status() === 200 && res.url().endsWith(".xml")
    );

    //Click on Form 4 link to the left
    const a = await page.waitForSelector(".filetype .preview-file");
    await a.click();


    const html = await (await responseP).text();
    await page.evaluate(html => document.body.outerHTML = html, html);

    //Get the info about the stocks price
    const price = await page.$$eval(".FormText", els =>
      els.find(e => e.textContent.trim() === "$")//Search for a node with a "$" symbol
        .parentNode
        .textContent
        .replace("$", "")
        .replace("(1)", "")
        .trim()
    );

    const Price = parseInt(price); //Convert price from string to number

    await page.reload({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();

    // -------------------- IF STATEMENT --------------------
    // If Price is less than $0.1, throw exception
    if (Price < 0.1 || null || undefined) {
      throw "Price is 0"
    } else {
      return Price;
    }
    // -------------------- IF STATEMENT --------------------

  })()
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

PS: The `price` is exported as a module to the index.js as `priceModule` and I made an if statement that throws an error when the conditions are true, but that doesn't produce the effect I wanted, it just prints the error onto the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with cronjobs, but I would guess that the if statement needs to be inside the cronjob:

```
    const job = new cronjob("0 14-23 * * *", () => {
        if( !condition ) {
            tweet();
            console.log("Tweet executed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay I could do that but it doesn't make too much of a difference, how do I stop execution if the condition is true?

Comment: my example only executes when the condition is false.
!condition is the same as condition == false

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to call it just before the tweet and based on the output use try-catch.
Something like

```
const job = new cronjob("0 14-23 * * *", () => {
        try{
            price()
        } catch (error) {
            tweet();
            console.log("Tweet executed");
        }
    });
```

Or a better way if your price.js file is modifiable if price is 0 then rather than throw `Price is 0` do `return null` and in your cron

```
const job = new cronjob("0 14-23 * * *", () => {
        let price = price()
        if(price === null){
            tweet();
            console.log("Tweet executed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: In the fist solution, how come the thing I want to execute is in the `catch()`? Isn't that only for errors?

Comment: Correct that is for errors 
because in your price file you are throwing `throw "Price is 0"` if Price is less than $0.1 It would throw an exception and enter the catch which can be used to trigger 
tweet()